# how to adjust gap between labels html/css?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I want to adjust labels text gap automatically between labels.

1. "Labels" are under the "Buttons".

Here is the code:

```
<style>
 .btn{
   margin-right: 5px;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   position:relative;
  }
  .btn label {
   display: block;
   position:relative;

   }
</style>


<!-- Html Part - All show horizontically -->
<button class="btn">Medicine 1</button>
<button class="btn">Medicine 2</button>
<button class="btn">Medicine 3</button>
<button class="btn">Medicine 4</button>
<br>

<!-- here I want to adjust position button relative -->
<!-- I want position/gap of labels adjust automatically under the buttons  -->
<!-- Labels under the buttons looks good and aligned-->


<label class="btn">2 mg</label>
<label class="btn">500 mg</label>
<label class="btn">650 mg</label>
<label class="btn">250 mg</label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Did you just link to the ***index page*** of jsfiddle??

Comment: did you think of using a table for that purpose?

Comment: @ruud how to achieve that in a table?

Comment: I saw Osama already tried to explain it. In short, you make a table In which you put button 1 in the first column, first row, label 2 in the first column, second row, buton 2 in the first row of the 2nd column, etcetara. Which garantees the buttons and label will be aligned. Maybe it is a good starting point to read a html tutorial on tables and experiment with that.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `margin-bottom: 15px` to the `.btn label` css that you have in your code. Keep the rest of the code too because label is in fact an inline-element so you have to override it to `display: block` so that it acts like a block element and only then would the margin work on it.

Comment: Try the table format. Just put buttons and labels inside two different rows of a table. You can align the label under the button using `text-algnment: center` on the labels row `td` and then if you want spacing, you can target the specific row of labels and add a `padding-top` like
`table>tr>td:nth-child(2)`

Comment: Your suggestions seems good but not understand "add a padding-top like table>tr>td:nth-child(2)" .

Comment: I'm sorry I mistyped, it should be `table tr:nth-child(2) td{padding-top:20px}`. What this does is that it searches for a table, finds the 2nd child table row `tr` and inside on all table data `td`s and applies a `padding-top` of `20px`

Comment: I am not getting. Can you please provide your suggestion on https://jsfiddle.net/. I am a beginner and not able to understand properly.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vn6cs5q3/19/) out and let me know if you understand.